# Emmet Conflict with Atom Autocompletion

Tags: github, atom-editor, emmet

I am following this instructions (https://atom.io/packages/emmet) using Git Bash. The problem is the last step which is "npm install". It's said command  not found.

I can successfully install emmet in Atom editor, but the problem is it messes with the code autosuggestion, and when I press tab, it doesn't write what it ought to.

See also this: https://github.com/emmetio/atom-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you don't have npm installed on your computer.
You might want to read https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm